# DeBrujin sequence in 2D case

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

There is a known way to generate 2d Array built from elements of alphabet containing N values, in which each overlapped window of size (width x  height) K1 x K2 occurs only once?

Comment: That would be a De Bruijn torus. According to wikipedia, for K1 != K2, this is an open question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming, tools, algorithms or software development.

Comment: Lidae, is there an known mainstream algorithm to generate 2D De Brujin Torus?